# Add line shapefile to 3D raster plot in rasterVis

Tags: raster, r, line

I have generated a 3D raster plot using the plot3D function in the rasterVis package in R.

For enhanced data visualisation, **I want to add a line shapefile**, representing a sampling transect, **to the 3D plot**.

Does anyone know how to do this in R?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lines3d` from the `rgl` package but make sure to plot the raster with `adjust=FALSE` or the axes won't line up.

Where `r` is a raster and `xyz` is a data frame with x, y, z (height) locations, I do:

```
plot3D(r, col = rainbow, adjust=FALSE)
lines3d(xyz)
```

and get

[image]

You can get the heights of points from the raster using `extract` if you don't have them already, and you might want to add a little offset to the heights to keep them just clear of the terrain, so they don't get clipped by any interpolation. You can see my line gets a bit clipped because it's a rough transect with only ten points.

You can use any `rgl` package functions to augment that plot, such as `axis3d("x")` to show the x-axis.